# Can you use uiOutput in a shiny Dashboard?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build a shiny Dashboard and I would like to use uiOutput.

In my ui.R file in the dashboardSidebar I have a menuitem that calls uiOutput:

```
library(shiny)
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("TCA", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
      menuItem(uiOUtput("Symbols")) ....
```

my server.r file looks like:

```
 output$Symbols<-renderUI({
    selectInput('Test', 'Test:', choices = c(1,2,3), selected = 1)
  })
```

When I run the app:

```
## app.R ##
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I get an error:

```
Error in tag("span", list(...)) : could not find function "uiOUtput"
```

Do you know how to use shinyDashboard with uiOutput?

Comment: Well, firstly you have a typo.  It is `uiOutput` not `uiOUtput`.  Check that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you correct the typo the following works for me.  You should be able to use `uiOuput`.

```
library(shinydashboard)
runApp(
    list(ui = dashboardPage(
        dashboardHeader(),
        dashboardSidebar(
            sidebarMenu(
                menuItem(uiOutput("Symbols"))
            )
        ),
        dashboardBody()
    )

    , server = function(input, output) {   

        output$Symbols<-renderUI({
            selectInput('Test', 'Test:', choices = c(1,2,3), selected = 1)
        })
    }
    )
)
```